# HTTP GET request not working in java when HTTP is 1.1?

Tags: java, httprequest

so i made a little code that can download 4chan pages. i get the raw HTML page and parse it for my need. the code below was working fine but it suddenly stopped working. when i run it the server does not accept my request it seems its waiting for something more. however i know that HTTP request is as below

```
GET /ck HTTP/1.1
Host: boards.4chan.org
(extra new line)
```

if i change this format in anyway i revive "400 bad request" status code. but if i change HTTP/1.1 to 1.0 the server responses in "200 ok" status and i get the whole page. so this makes me thing the error is in the host line since that became mandatory in HTTP/1.1. but still i cannot figure out what exactly need to be changed.

the calling function simply this, to get one whole board

```
downloadHTMLThread( "ck", -1);
```

or for a specific thread u just change -1 to that number. for example like for the link below will have like below.

```
//http://boards.4chan.org/ck/res/3507158
//url.getDefaultPort() is 80
//url.getHost() is boards.4chan.org
//url.getFile() is /ck/res/3507158

downloadHTMLThread( "ck", 3507158);
```

any advise would be appreciated, thanks

```
public static final String BOARDS = "boards.4chan.org";
public static final String IMAGES = "images.4chan.org";
public static final String THUMBS = "thumbs.4chan.org";
public static final String RES = "/res/";
public static final String HTTP = "http://";
public static final String SLASH = "/";

public String downloadHTMLThread( String board, int thread) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    String str = null;
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(HTTP+BOARDS+SLASH+board+(thread==-1?SLASH:RES+thread));
        socket = new Socket( url.getHost(), url.getDefaultPort());
        reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        out.println( "GET " +url.getFile()+ " HTTP/1.1");
        out.println( "HOST: " + url.getHost());
        out.println();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            input.append( str).append("\r\n");
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println( input);
        System.out.println( "\nTime: " +(end-start)+ " milliseconds");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         input = null;
    } finally {
        if( reader!=null){
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
        if( socket!=null){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
        if( out!=null){
            out.close();
        }
    }
    return input==null? null: input.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) instead of rolling your own:

```
static String getUriContentsAsString(String uri) throws IOException {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
  return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
```

If you are doing this to really learn the internals of HTTP client requests, then you might start by playing with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) from the command line.  This will let you get all your headers and request body squared away.  Then it will be a simple matter of adjusting your request to match what works in curl.

Comment: i have another code that works with Apache, but my intend was to modify this later on for smartphones, so i would rather not use third party libraries.

Comment: Please listen to James and do yourself a favor: Use Apache HttpClient. If by smartphone you mean Android, [Apache HttpClient is built-in](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html).

Comment: i do agree, but nothing beats writing the raw code. and i am just curious now because this is getting annoying

Comment: @James: I had a code sample but you replied first, so I allowed myself to just add it to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

By the code I think that you are sending 'HOST' instead of 'Host'. Since this is a compulsory header in http/1.1, but ignored in http/1.0, that might be the problem. 
Anyway, you could use a program to capture the packet sent (i. e. wireshark), just to make sure.
Using println is quite useful, but the line separator appended to the command depends on the system property line.separator. I think (although I'm not sure) that the line separator used in http protocol has to be '\r\n'. If you're capturing the packet, I think it'd be a good idea to check that each line sent ends with '\r\n' (bytes x0D0A) (just in case your os line separator is different)

Answer (score 0):

Use www.4chan.org as the host instead.  Since boards.4chan.org is a 302 redirect to www.4chan.org, you won't be able to scrape anything from boards.4chan.org.

Comment: i have actually checked that already when i use 4chan.org i get "301 Moved Permanently". i checked the host with Firefox console when in the site and the host is boards.4chan.org

Comment: Have you tried using www.4chan.org as the host? (not 4chan.org)